# elem.style.height not triggered inside while loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar, progress

I want to make a progress bar that "collapses" when done. 
By collapse, I mean repeatedly decrease height by `1`.

But when the progress bar "is done" (reaches width 100), nothing more happens.

This is my code:

```
               function frame() {
                    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
                    var height = 30;
                    if (width >= 100) {
                        while (elem.style.height != 0) {
                            elem.style.height = height + '%';
                            height--;
                        }
                        clearInterval(id);
                    } else {
                        width++; 
                        elem.style.width = width + '%';
                    }
                }
```

Where is the error?

Sorry if my question is silly or a duplicate; I searched the forum but found no duplicate post.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have done this

```
 elem.style.height = height + '%';
```

The following will never be false:

```
while (elem.style.height != 0)
```

Becase this is false:

```
"0%"==0 // false
```

And I think there is something wrong with the loop. If you want to decrease the height one by one, it is better to call a setInterval, as a loop will change the height to 0 in less than 1ms, which has no difference with setting the height to 0 directly.

Comment: Thank you. Will use setInterval instead.